# Why does my fade animation only work on the first click event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm having trouble applying the text fade animation to the `<p>` of the `.item-text`. It only works on the first click. After that, it doesn't work anymore.

```js
//Menu Slide Function
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('a.toggle-nav');
const toggleMain = document.querySelector('main');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const toggler = toggleMain.classList.toggle("open");
  if (toggler == true) {
    toggleBtn.innerHTML = `<img src = https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/x-03-icon-256x256-lxg5kn7w.png> Close`
  } else {
    toggleBtn.innerHTML = `<img src = https://www.shareicon.net/download/2015/08/09/82576_menu.ico> Menu`
  }
})

//Slideshow Function
const slideArea = document.querySelector('div.item-img')
const mangaCovers = document.querySelectorAll('div.item-img img')
const mangaDesc = document.querySelector('div.item-text p')
const mangaTitles = document.querySelector('div.item-text h1')
const mangaDescList = [
  'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente totam numquam assumenda placeat dolorum accusantium expedita quis odit, inventore quasi ut.',
  'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente totam numquam assumenda placeat dolorum accusantium expedita quis odit, inventore quasi ut.',
  'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente totam numquam assumenda placeat dolorum accusantium expedita quis odit, inventore quasi ut.',
  'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente totam numquam assumenda placeat dolorum accusantium expedita quis odit, inventore quasi ut.,
  'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente totam numquam assumenda placeat dolorum accusantium expedita quis odit, inventore quasi ut.,
  'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente totam numquam assumenda placeat dolorum accusantium expedita quis odit, inventore quasi ut.'
];
const mangaTitlesList = [
  'Title 1',
  'Title 2',
  'Title 3',
  'Title 4',
  'Title 5',
  'Title 6'
]

let z = 1;
let currentSlide = 0

slideArea.addEventListener('click', function() {
  currentSlide = currentSlide + 1;
  z = z + 1;

  mangaCovers.forEach(function(cover) {
    cover.style.animation = ""
  })



  if (currentSlide > mangaCovers.length - 1) {
    currentSlide = 0;
  }

  mangaCovers[currentSlide].style.zIndex = z;
  mangaCovers[currentSlide].style.animation = 'fade 0.5s';

  mangaDesc.innerHTML = mangaDescList[currentSlide];
  mangaTitles.innerHTML = mangaTitlesList[currentSlide];

  mangaDesc.style.animation = 'fade 0.5s';


})

slideArea.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {

  mangaCovers.forEach(function(cover) {
    const x = 25 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 50
    const y = 25 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 50
    cover.style.transform = `translate(${x}px , ${y}px)`

  })
})

slideArea.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {

  mangaCovers.forEach(function(cover) {
    cover.style.transform = ''

  })

})
```

```css
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* img {
  height: auto;
  width: 350px;
} */

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 25vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orangered;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

nav a {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 1em;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

a img {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
}

main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

main.open {
  transform: translate(25vh, 0);
}

.toggle-nav {
  /* margin-left: 30%; */
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  left: 2em;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  gap: 3em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.item-text {
  /* margin-top: -15em; */
  width: 30em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
}

.item-title {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.item-desc {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

.item-cta {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: orangered;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div.item-img {
  position: relative;
}

div.item-img img {
  width: 370px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -250px;
  left: -400px;
  transition: transform 0.5s, box-shadow 0.5s;
}

div.item-img img:first-child {
  z-index: 1;
}

div.item-img:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- navigation bar of the site -->
  <nav>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="products.html">Products</a>
    <a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
  </nav>


  <main>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-nav">
      <img src="https://www.shareicon.net/download/2015/08/09/82576_menu.ico" id="menu-icon"> Menu
    </a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item-img" id="item-img">
        <img src="x.html">
        <img src="x.html">
        <img src="x.html">
        <img src="x.html">
        <img src="x.html">
        <img src="x.html">
      </div>
      <div class="item-text">
        <div class="item-title">
          <h1>Beginner Manga Recos</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item-desc">
          <p>Here are the manga I'd like to recommend to people just starting. Hope you enjoy!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="https://mangadex.org/" class="item-cta">Read Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>
```

I tried this statement: `mangaDesc.style.animation = 'fade 0.5s';` but it only works once.

The intended behaviour is for every time I click the `slideArea` there should be a text fade animation to the `<p>`.

Thank you all in advance!

PS: I had to remove the image links as Stack Overflow keeps on flagging my question as a spam.

Comment: Once you e set the animation and it’s run the system won’t spot that you’ve set it again, it thinks it’s done it. So you need to remove the animation on animationend event so the next time you set it it will run.

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance, @AHaworth! I appreciate it a lot. I added `setTimeout(() => {
        mangaDesc.style.animation = ''; }, 220);` and it worked! Was wondering though if setTimeout was the best fix for this problem or if it there was a better solution.

Comment: I would listen for the animationend event but it doesn’t make much odds.